# Autodiscover error 600 from Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, ssl-certificate, outlook, autodiscover

I am having trouble with my exchange 2019 server.  I've narrowed it down to an autodiscover problem.  First of all the (outlook 2013) client complains about an invalid cert on the exchange server, but I have imported my CA cert to the clients, and the Exchange cert is a wildcard (*.MYDOMAIN.COM) so I should be ok.

More importantly, when I put the URL https://exchange.MYDOMAIN.COM/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml into a browser I see:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
<Response>
<Error Time="09:47:13.8695372" Id="3007185755">
<ErrorCode>600</ErrorCode>
<Message>Invalid Request</Message>
<DebugData/>
</Error>
</Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

Based on other posts I thought I would show this output from the Exchange server:

```
[PS] C:\Users\administrator.MYDOMAIN\Desktop>Get-OutlookProvider

Name Server CertPrincipalName TTL
---- ------ ----------------- ---
EXCH                          1
EXPR                          1
WEB                           1


[PS] C:\Users\administrator.MYDOMAIN\Desktop>Get-OutlookAnywhere


RunspaceId                         : c5b8cea3-f65f-4e3c-b746-ef68229eff00
ServerName                         : EXCHANGE
SSLOffloading                      : True
ExternalHostname                   : exchange.MYDOMAIN.COM
InternalHostname                   : exchange.MYDOMAIN
ExternalClientAuthenticationMethod : Ntlm
InternalClientAuthenticationMethod : Ntlm
IISAuthenticationMethods           : {Ntlm}
XropUrl                            :
ExternalClientsRequireSsl          : True
InternalClientsRequireSsl          : True
MetabasePath                       : IIS://exchange.MYDOMAIN.COM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Rpc
Path                               : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\rpc
ExtendedProtectionTokenChecking    : None
ExtendedProtectionFlags            : {}
ExtendedProtectionSPNList          : {}
AdminDisplayVersion                : Version 15.2 (Build 1118.7)
Server                             : EXCHANGE
AdminDisplayName                   :
ExchangeVersion                    : 0.20 (15.0.0.0)
Name                               : Rpc (Default Web Site)
DistinguishedName                  : CN=Rpc (Default Web Site),CN=HTTP,CN=Protocols,CN=EXCHANGE,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange
                                     Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative
                                     Groups,CN=MYDOMAIN,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM
Identity                           : EXCHANGE\Rpc (Default Web Site)
Guid                               : 57e3c79d-2a35-465a-85a6-bb31c36c682a
ObjectCategory                     : MYDOMAIN.COM/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Rpc-Http-Virtual-Directory
ObjectClass                        : {top, msExchVirtualDirectory, msExchRpcHttpVirtualDirectory}
WhenChanged                        : 12/27/2020 3:05:40 PM
WhenCreated                        : 12/27/2020 2:29:01 PM
WhenChangedUTC                     : 12/27/2020 8:05:40 PM
WhenCreatedUTC                     : 12/27/2020 7:29:01 PM
OrganizationId                     :
Id                                 : EXCHANGE\Rpc (Default Web Site)
OriginatingServer                  : domctl.MYDOMAIN.COM
IsValid                            : True
ObjectState                        : Changed
```

I looked in the root directory for the "Autodiscover" site on the exchange server and there is NO autodiscover.xml file.  Am I supposed to manually create one?  (Or is this dynamically created).

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You can create a generic local auto discover.xml, and define an HKCU registry value for the location. That may enable you to proceed further, but at a fundamental level Outlook 2013 is end of life.  It can also be problematic due to many organizations simply aren't capable of updating legacy Office apps, and 2013 is one of the more problematic versions, particularly for Outlook. https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/autodiscoverconfiguration.htm

Comment: Maybe ignore Outlook 2013 for the moment.  Even trying to retrieve the autodiscover.xml via a browser yields error 600, a code that isn't even listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code.  What is wrong on the Exchange IIS server side?

Comment: Error 600 actually indicates the autodiscover process succeeded.

You can run a Test E-Mail Autoconfiguration on the affected Outlook client.
Follow these steps: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mailboxes-test-e-mail-autoconfiguration/19f9c90a-4640-46c4-a574-dbec29bdb8ba

Comment: Based on the above, it seems other apps & browsers (and Outlook 2019+) are all ok with the above.  Outlook 2013 seems to be the only app breaking on the fact that exchange does not have autodiscover.MYDOMAIN.COM as an ASN on the cert. (but does have *.MYDOMAIN.COM).  Very strange....still searching